# Конкретезировать константу шаблонного класса в зависимости от части параметров шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Часто встречается такая задача: класс имеет определенные константы, значения которых полностью определяются по части параметров шаблона.
Как я решаю это сейчас показано ниже.
Уверен, что есть решение попроще, без лишних статических функций. Может кто посоветует.

```
template<class T, uint16_t s>
static const uint16_t Size();

template<class T, class U, uint16_t s>
class Test
{
    void method()
    {
        ...
        doSomething ( Size<T,s>() );
    }
    ...
};

template<> const uint16_t Size<SomeType1, SomeN1>() { return 3; }
template<> const uint16_t Size<SomeType2, SomeN2>() { return 5; }
```

Comment: У тебя хорошое решение. Только слово `static` лишнее. Если там все всегда константа, добавь constexpr вместо static, тогда компилятор заменить Size<>() на число.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А шаблоны переменных не годятся? [Типа](https://ideone.com/NVRHVd)

```
template<class T, int N>
int Val = 3;

template<>
int Val<int,0> = 5;


template<int N>
int Val<char,N> = N;


template<class T, int N>
class Test
{
public:
    void method()
    {
        cout << Val<T,N> << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test<int,0> t1;
    t1.method();
    Test<int,5> t2;
    t2.method();
    Test<char,7> t3;
    t3.method();
}
```

Comment: А эта шаблонная переменная может быть параметром шаблона?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду что-то такого типа? - https://ideone.com/OcNWRi - или я неверно понял ваш вопрос?

Comment: Всё верно поняли, правда не параметр шаблона класса, а внутри класса вызывать шаблонные функции с этим параметром вместо передачи параметра в функцию.